# how to convert <QuerySet [<Course: BME108_JUL2020>]> to 'BME108' in python?

Tags: django, python-3.6

I use django2 with python3.6 in windows 10.
I want to query the sqlite database in Django.

when I tried to add condition to the query, I should use the condition passed by the last query.
However, the result of the last query is:  <QuerySet [<Course: BME108_JUL2020>]>.

The condition I need is 'BME108'

view.py:

```
course_code = Course.objects.filter(semester_id = semester_id_1, term = 1)
query_results_3 = 
courseInfo.objects.filter(code=course_code[:5]).values('title')
```

models.py

```
class CourseInfo(TimeStampedModel):  # school or center
code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
postgraduate = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # indicate Postgraduate course
discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)  # should not be null
pattern = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PRESENTATION_PATTERN, blank=True, null=True,
                           help_text="Presentation Pattern")
type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(('PT', 'Part-Time'), ('FT', 'Full-Time'), ('OL', 'Online')))
available = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # mean Active or Retired

semesters = models.ManyToManyField('Semester', through="Course")  # auto have semestercourse_set

# __str__ method is used to override default string returned by an object
def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.code, self.title)

class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['code', 'type'], condition=models.Q(available=True),
                                           name='unique_course_type')]
    ordering = ['code', ]


class Course(models.Model):  # CourseInfo Quota
courseInfo = models.ForeignKey(CourseInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
term = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # Optional, Term start: 1 or 2
quota = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # total student enrolment

titles = models.ManyToManyField('Title', through="Material")  # performance issue, it will load all books, for the DRF only

class Meta:
    # must add unique_together for course, course_type and semester
    ordering = ('semester',)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}_{}".format(self.courseInfo.code, self.semester)
```

How could I convert    <QuerySet [<Course: BME108_JUL2020>]>    to    'BME108'?

Comment: Please share the code how you get that queryset?

Comment: Share your models and views

Comment: updated @Ajay Kumar

Comment: showed now @SergeyPugach   , course_code is queryset

Answer (score 0):

Replace the str function of the Course model with this code

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.courseInfo.code)
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer but it would be beneficial if you could explain your code a bit so that it is clear what you're doing :)

Answer (score 0):

First adapt the `__str__` function in your Course model like this:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.courseInfo.code}"
```

That way, when you just print a Course object, it shows you only the code.

Next up, you want to get that element out of the QuerySet. This can be done in multiple ways. You could for example loop over it like how you would do with a list. Or, if it is always the first item that you want, you can use .first() on the QuerySet.

Given you changed the above `__str__` function, this will deliver the output you desire:

```py
course_code = Course.objects.filter(semester_id = semester_id_1, term = 1)
print(course_code.first()) # prints the first item
```

or

```py
course_code = Course.objects.filter(semester_id = semester_id_1, term = 1)
for result in course_code: # prints all items separately
  print(result)
```

Comment: error shows 'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '
ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.   in   for result in query_results:

Comment: sorry, i mixed up the queries. try now.